# How to start an animation on the active slide with Swiper.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, swiper.js

I'm trying to animate the nav elements that are outside of the swiper-slide with basic animations like changing the text color to black when the 2end and 3rd slide is active
here is my code

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper-container-h">

<!---------- NAV START ---------->

                 <div class="nav">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <h1>nerv</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login">
                        <button class="login-icon" data-modal-target="#modal">
                            <img src="images/Icons/login.png"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ctgris">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Womens.php">WOMENS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Mens.php">MENS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">KIDS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                
                <!----- NAV END ----->
                
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide slide1">
                        <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-v">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                <div class="swiper-slide slide1">
                                    <div class="caption anmt-v">
                                        <h1>BUILDING DREMAS THROW CLOTHES</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide slide2">
                                    <div class="caption anmt-v">
                                        <h1>BUILDING DREMAS THROW CLOTHES</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide slide3">
                                    <div class="caption anmt-v">
                                        <h1>BUILDING DREMAS THROW CLOTHES</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Add Arrows -->
                            <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-next-v"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev-v"></div>
                            <!-- Add Pagination -->
                            <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-v"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide slide2">
                        <!-- Add Arrows -->
                        <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-next-h"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev-h"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide slide3">
                        <!-- Add Arrows -->
                        <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev-h"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Add Pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-h"></div>
```

this is my js to init swiper and trigger animaions of elements inside of swiper-slide

```
var swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
    speed: 1500,
    keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next-h',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev-h',
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination-h',
        dynamicBullets: true,
        clickable: true,
    },
    on: {
        slideChangeTransitionStart: function () {
            $('.anmt-h').hide(0);
        },
        slideChangeTransitionEnd: function () {
            $('.anmt-h').show(0);
        },
    }
});

'''

any help would be appreciated
```

Comment: Posting your code on a platform like codepen would be very helpfull so that the community can see your code in action.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this is finding the current index in you custom function.
Hookup the action to the slideTransitionEnd, and use the **realIndex** property which would have been updated.

```
slideChangeTransitionEnd: function () {
  $('.anmt-h').show(0);
  var myCurrentSlide = this.realIndex;
 //set the action
  if(myCurrentSlide != 0){
   //perform action to change color 
  }
  else {
  //perform action to reset the function
  }
}
```

Your color change function can be a direct js manipulation or better a class change after defining the class styles. for my example code I expect it to add the class `isBlack`

```
  $(".ctgris li").each(function(n){
if(n>0){ 
  if(n == myCurrentIndex){ $(this).addClass("isBlack")}
}else{ $(this).removeClass("isBlack")}
})
```

example CSS

```
.isBlack {
  color:black;
}
```